# What is the mistake in the following code?

Tags: c, arrays

while running, max is giving desired maximum number from the list of numbers but the min is not giving minimum number which it is supposed to give.?
For example:

If the input is :

> 5 
> 45 7 2 1 4

The output from the below code is:

> Maximum number is 45
>
> Minimum number is 0

Why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define MX 1000000

int max=INT_MIN;
int min=INT_MAX;

int findmax(int a[],int n)
{
    if(n<0)
        return max;
    if(a[n]>max)
    {
        max=a[n];
    }
    return findmax(a,n-1);
}

int findmin(int a[],int n)
{
    if(n<0)
        return min;
    if(a[n]<min)
    {
        min=a[n];
    }
    return findmin(a,n-1);
}

int main(void) {
    int a[MX],n,i;
    printf("Enter the number of elements:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("Maximum number is %d\n",findmax(a,n));
    printf("Minimum number is %d\n",findmin(a,n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did it run ? It crashed on my system .

Comment: What is the output that you are getting.

Comment: 0) `int a[MX]` too big on stack.

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through the program in a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the array elements from n-1 not from n. So make a function calls in this way **findmax(a,n-1)** **findmin(a,n-1)**

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you're *initializing* values for the index 0 to `n-1`, but inside the `findmax()` and `findmin()`, you're using index `n`. That value is not initialized to anything (`a` is automatic local variable, remember?), and the value at that index (content) in indeterministic.

So, accessing using that index actually is an attempt to read an unitialized variable which invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Make the call to `findmax()` and `findmin()` with `n-1` as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

Using global variables is not considered a good design. If you are not obsessed with recursive functions, you can simplify your code to

```
int findmax(int a[], int n) {
    int i = 0, max = INT_MIN;
    for (; i < n; ++i)
        if (max < a[i])
            max = a[i];
    return max;
}
```

Similarly for `findmin`.